# A substitution for a function of a vector with variable dimension

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have to define a function with a recurring pattern like

$u[\mathbb{x}] = x_1^{\alpha_1} x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$

With the help of an older post, it is easily done

```
 u[x : {__}, α : {__}] := Times @@ (x^α)
u[{u, v, x, y, 
  z}, {α, β, γ, ϵ, θ}]
xx = Table[Subscript[x, 
  i], {i, 1, 
   5}](*{Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], \
Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5]}*)
αα = 
 Table[Subscript[α, 
  i], {i, 1, 
   5}](*{Subscript[α, 1],Subscript[α, 2], Subscript[\
α, 3],Subscript[α, 4], Subscript[α, 5]}*)
u[xx, αα]
```

Now I want to write the gradient  `Grad[]` of U. One more time, it is fairly easy:

```
grad[u_]:= Grad[u[xx, αα], xx]
```

Now comes my problem: whichever be the dimension of `xx`, each derivative, which is an element of `grad[u]`, incorporate a pattern of the form

$u_{x_i}[\mathbb{x}] = x_1^{\alpha_1} x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots \alpha_i x_i^{\alpha_i-1} \cdots x_n^{\alpha_n} = \alpha_i\frac{u}{x_i}$

So I want to substitute this pattern in grad[u] simplify the representation of the gradient. If `Dimensions[xx]` is always the same, it is not too complicated to do the substitution. For instance if `Dimensions[xx]= 3`, I would use the vectors ${x, y, z}$ and ${\alpha, \beta, \gamma}$ and  do  the substitution:

```
//.{α_ x_^(α_-1) y_^β_ y_^γ_ -> α (u/x)}
```

but

1) I want to keep the indexed variables and  the indexed  parameters;

2) the process must work whichever be the `Dimensions[xx]`.

Perhaps the good idea would be to write a substitution formula of the type

$\forall i$ `grad[u][[i]]->` $\alpha_i u/x_i$

I use here a mix of Mathematica and Latex since I do not know how to encode this.

Comment: Would you kindly provide a sample input and output fully in *Mathematica* code?  I am not sure I follow your notation.

Comment: Mr Wizard I may have found the solution Table[Replace[grad[fu2][[i]], 
  grad[fu2][[i]] ->  (Subscript[\[Alpha], i] u )/Subscript[x, 
   i] ], {i, 1, 6}].

Comment: self-answers are welcome on Stack Exchange :-)

Comment: I will give the solution in the following hours, but it will open new questions.